# Calculate difftime as Sys.Date if field is NA in R

Tags: r

Quite simply I want to calculate tenure, if an employee is termed, then I want the new field to return Term. Date - Job.Entry.Date to calculate tenure. Otherwise, if the employee is active, then I want the new field to return Sys.Date - Job.Entry.Date.

With the following Code:

```
jobentrydat_alltechs$Tenure <-if (jobentrydat_alltechs$Term.Date == is.na) {
  return (difftime(Sys.Date(), jobentrydat_alltechs$Job.Entry.Date, units = c("days")))
} else if (jobentrydat_alltechs$Term.Date != is.na) {
    return (difftime(jobentrydat_alltechs$Term.Date, jobentrydat_alltechs$Job.Entry.Date, units = c("days")))
}
```

I am getting the following error

> Error in `==.default`(jobentrydat_alltechs$Term.Date, is.na) :
>   comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types

Comment: Please supply a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `ifelse` instead of `if`, as it's vectorized, and also `is.na` is a function, not a value to be compared with.

```
jobentrydat_alltechs$Tenure <- ifelse(is.na(jobentrydat_alltechs$Term.Date),
  difftime(Sys.Date(), jobentrydat_alltechs$Job.Entry.Date, units = c("days")),
  difftime(jobentrydat_alltechs$Term.Date, jobentrydat_alltechs$Job.Entry.Date, units = c("days")))
```

Comment: I attempted it as you have with both ifelse and is.na(jobentrydat_alltechs$Term.Date) but was getting another error. I see my true error was beginning with an if, then ifelse as opposed to ifelse. Thanks.